# Springboot - How to access cacerts file from local classpath using manifest.yml

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, ssl-certificate, microservices

Below is a snap of my manifest file.
I am using JDK 8

```
env:
JAVA_OPTS: -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=classpath:resources/config/cacerts
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=classpath:resources/config/cacerts
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

Have added debug option as well like below.

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl
```

For some reason I am getting below error when I hit my application.
My end system uses https, and I am getting error on PCF as below.

> java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing
>   implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class:
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext); nested exception
>   is java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException:
>   Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider:
>   SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)

Comment: perhaps your  `trustStore` set wrongly ?

Comment: Its working for others, I am trying to see if this method works since I am migrating to new buildpack from an older version.